# Convert WCF Service from .NET 4.5 to .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-3.5

I have a selfhosted WCF Service written in Visual Studio 2013 Pro (.NET 4.5). It perfectly works when I run it in .NET 4.5. However, when I change my project settings to .NET 3.5, I get an InvalidOperationException.

```
namespace ProcessingLayer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(ProcessingService)); // -> InvalidOperationException
            host.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Host Open Sucessfully ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
    public interface IProcessingService
    {
        [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
        void startSession(string s);

        [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = false)]
        Feature getFeatureData();

        [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false, IsTerminating = true)]
        void terminateSession();
    }

    public class ProcessingService : IProcessingService
    {
        // Omitted for reasons of pace and space
    }
}
```

*app.config*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>      
      <netTcpBinding>
        <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IProcessingService"/>
      </netTcpBinding>      
      <netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="NetNamedPipeBinding_IProcessingService"/>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ProcessingLayer.ProcessingServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>    
    <services>
      <service name="ProcessingLayer.ProcessingService">        
        <endpoint address="ProcessingService" binding="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="ProcessingLayer.IProcessingService" bindingConfiguration="NetNamedPipeBinding_IProcessingService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>        
        <endpoint address="ProcessingService" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ProcessingLayer.IProcessingService" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IProcessingService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>        
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>        
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9001/ProcessingLayer/ProcessingService/"/>
            <add baseAddress="net.pipe://localhost/ProcessingLayer/ProcessingService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>        
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I need to change it from .NET 4.5 to .NET 3.5 because of compatibility issues with a client application. As I only have VS 2010 and VS 2013, I cannot follow the obsolete .NET 3.5 Tutorials, because those assume VS 2008.

How can I change it from .NET 4.5 to 3.5?

Comment: I suggest creating a dummy WCF 3.5 app and reviewing the config file. most of what drastically changed from 3.5->4.0->4.5 was in the config, therefore you're likely missing a lot of things that .NET starts to supply default settings for in newer versions of WCF.

Comment: What is the `Message` in the `InvalidOperationException`?  There should be a description of the issue in that property.  Your config looks correct for 3.5.  Is your service implementation using anything that is in framework 4.0 or later?